# Teste de Aceitação com redirecionamento de URL

Tags: php, testes

Olá estou tentando gerar um **teste de aceitação** para minha página de login utilizando **codeception** e **Yii2**, só que o problema é que após o login o usuário é redirecionado para a página principal e lá o usuário, já logado, visualiza uma mensagem de boas vindas. Já tentei de várias maneiras mas não consegui prosseguir. Alguem podem me ajudar! Obrigado.

```
use \AcceptanceTester;

class LoginCest
{
    public function login(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->am('Login Page');
        $I->wantTo('Login Exists?');
        $I->amOnPage('/index.php?r=site/login');
        $I->see('Title');
        $I->see('User');
        $I->see('Password');
    }

    /**
    * @after login
    */
    public function validLogin(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/index.php?r=site/login');
        $I->fillField('LoginForm[username]', 'username');
        $I->fillField('LoginForm[password]', 'password');
        $I->click('Login');
        $I->amOnPage('/index.php');
        $I->see('Welcome {UserName}!', 'h1');
    }
}

Scenario Steps:
6. I see "Welcome!","h1" <<< FAIL
5. I am on page "/index.php"
4. I click "Login"
3. I fill field "LoginForm[password]","username"
2. I fill field "LoginForm[username]","password"
1. I am on page "/index.php?r=site/login"

FAILURES! Tests: 2, Assertions: 4, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: não compreendi bem sua pergunta, ele NÃO deve ser redirecionado para a pagina index.php após realizar o login, é isso mesmo? Se for isso, sera que não esta errado esta instrução $I->amOnPage('/index.php'); ? pois você o redireciona para lá, após ele clicar em login.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno @PauloRoberto. Eu preciso verificar se aparece uma condição após o login do usuário, sendo que após este login o mesmo é redirecionado para a página inicial. Na verdade eu não estou conseguindo proceder pós login. Pois qualquer tentativa ele sempre retorna para a mesma pagina de login. Não sei se há necessidade de armazenar esse cookie/session do login em alguma variável antes, ou se ao clicar no login o codeception deveria subentender e dar continuidade na página segura do sistema.

Comment: Não conheço este framework que você esta utilizando para verificar alguma condição pelo menos com o Selenium WebDriver, eu utilizo um assertion ou uma espera implicita ou explicita, verifique se não esta faltando isso em seu script e depois o tratamento de session.

Comment: Estou implantando o Selenium no momento, creio que o problema seja resolvido já que no formato atual não possuo nenhuma forma de manipular esse tempo de espera. Talvez esse delay no login seja resolvido. Caso tenha sucesso, posto a resposta aqui, todavia obrigado.

Comment: Se precisar de ajuda com o Selenium, poste uma nova pergunta ai!

Comment: Pode deixar, que posto sim! Obrigado.